# Get documents by tags

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, logical-and

I've been using Firestore to build an Android app and I run into the next limitation that I have no idea to deal with it.

**I need to retrieve documents by tags that are stored in an array-field.** However, **there can be only one** [`whereArrayContains`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#wherearraycontains) **per query**. How am I supposed to get documents by more than one tag?

Can you think of any clever solution to that?

Comment: That last question is a technology recommendation, which is off-topic here on Stack Overflow. I recommend removing it to prevent your question from being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one `whereArrayContainsAny` condition on a query, but you can have up to 10 `whereArrayContains` conditions.

From the documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> - Cloud Firestore provides limited support for logical `OR` queries. The `in` and `array-contains-any` operators support a logical `OR` of up to 10 equality (`==`) or `array-contains` conditions on a single field. For other cases, create a separate query for each `OR` condition and merge the query results in your app.

> - You can use only one `in` or `array-contains-any` clause per query. You can't use both `in` and `array-contains-any` in the same query.

Comment: Are you sure? The documentation says something different: _A Query can have only one whereArrayContains() filter and it cannot be combined with whereArrayContainsAny()._ https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#wherearraycontains or have I misinterpreted it?

Comment: I also found this issue [Could we have more than one array-contains filter?](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1169) - the documentation seems to be inconsistent.

Comment: The link you shared also states that one can _use the array-contains-any operator to combine up to 10 array-contains clauses on the same field with a logical OR. An array-contains-any query returns documents where the given field is an array that contains one or more of the comparison value_ - if this only was a logical `AND` :-(

Comment: Not the prettiest option but I think I'll go with up to ten additional fields to represent the tags for now. This should be sufficient... unitl I find a replacement.